# Does IPC::Shareable work with blessed objects?

Tags: perl, oop, ipc

I would like to share a blessed object between two or more Perl applications. The object in question is quite expensive to instantiate, but always the same (static). The idea is to instantiate it once in one application and use it in other applications. This particular object is basically an http client using HTTP::Tiny an a whole bunch of other modules. Instantiating it via `new()` can take more than 50% of the total run time. I think the only module which may be a problem is the HTTP::Tiny since it open sockets, but not really sure. Can I use IPC::Shareable or some other method to share this http client among other applications?

Follow-up, are there any significant security issues with IPC::Shareable?

Answer (score 0):

It supports anything Storable can handle. So it can handle objects, but not file handles (incl sockets). File handles are process-specific anyway.

Access to the shared memory is controlled using the same permission system that is used to control access to files (via the `mode` option), so the security issues are the same as they are for files.